# Using FsCheck, the propertyCheck function is NOT recognized

Tags: f#, fscheck

The "propertyCheck" function that is referenced within my test method is NOT recognized when I attempt to build my test.

I thought that propertyChecked was a core function of the FsCheck framework?

What other ceremony do I need to perform?

```
module Tests.Units

open FsUnit
open NUnit.Framework
open NUnit.Core.Extensibility

open FsCheck.NUnit
open FsCheck.NUnit.Addin

let add x y = (x + y)

let commutativeProperty x y = 
    let result1 = add x y
    let result2 = add y x // reversed params
    result1 = result2

[<Test>]
let ``When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on parameter order``()=
    propertyCheck commutativeProperty |> should equal true
```

Comment: Use Check.Quick instead of propertyCheck.

Comment: What gave you the idea that there's a `propertyCheck` function in FsCheck?

Comment: Section: "Refactoring the common code" :: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing/

Comment: @ScottNimrod that function is defined in that post: "First, we'll write a function called propertyCheck..."

Comment: Ahh... Thanks for showing me that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Functional_S writes in the comment, you can use `Check.Quick`, although you should realise that `Check.Quick` only *reports* test results; it doesn't 'fail' if the property turns out to be falsifiable. In a unit test suite, `Check.QuickThrowOnFailure` is a better option, because, as the name implies, it'll throw on failure.

Since it looks like you're attempting to run properties from within a unit testing framework like NUnit, you should consider to instead use one of the Glue Libraries for FsCheck:

- [FsCheck.Nunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsCheck.Nunit)
- [FsCheck.Xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FsCheck.Xunit)

This would enable you to write properties using the `[<Property>]` attribute:

```
[<Property>]
let ``When I add two numbers, the result should not depend on parameter order``x y =
    let result1 = add x y
    let result2 = add y x // reversed params
    result1 = result2
```

Due to the poor extensibility API for NUnit, you can save yourself a lot of grief using xUnit.net instead of NUnit.